# Extract all data after a mentioned div using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

```
 <div id="content">
        <div class="sample1">sample text1</div>
        <div class="sample2">
           <span style="float:right">some text2</span>
           <b>some text2</b>
        </div>
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
        <p>paragraph 2</p> 
        <div class="sample3">sample text3</div>
   </div>
```

I want to extract all data that is coming after "sample2" class.
The output will show
paragraph 1
paragraph 2
sample text3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/div[@id = 'content']
    /div[@class = 'sample2']
        /following::*/text()
```

Comment: It is only showing first p tag not all data that coming after "sample2" class
The output should be show lik this 
paragraph 1
paragraph 2
sample text3

Comment: @Dark, It depends on how you execute it in your XML/XPath engine. This XPath returns node-set.